# проблемы с настройкой ноды bitcoin

Tags: php, node.js

Коллеги буду очень благодарен за помощь в подключению ноды биткоин провозился уже несколько дней но так и не поборол ..

пытаюсь подключиться к ноде для дальнейших операций с криптой но есть проблемы  так как сути работы не совсем понимаю и работаю по инструкциям

саму ноду установил по инструкции https://serveradmin.ru/ustanovka-i-nastroyka-nodyi-bitcoin-ethereum-dash-litecoin-cardano/ на сервер , в консоле проверил вроде как идет генерация 
пытаюсь подключиться с серверу через один из готовых классов 
https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP

но выбивает ошибку

```
 Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in ......./server.domain.com/public_html/easybitcoin.php:138
Stack trace:
#0 ...../server.domain.com/public_html/index.php(14): Bitcoin->__call('getinfo', Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in ...../server.domain.com/public_html/easybitcoin.php on line 138
```

ошибка в строке easybitcoin.php on line 138 ругается при отправке через curl 
и я не могу понять почему ругается или как протестировать вообще внешне работу моей ноды , логины пароли вроде как все верно , Ip  адрес использую своего сервера

и еще обратил внимание при выполнение команды netstat -tulnp | grep bitcoind не повязан мой ип адрес сервера хотя в конфиге я создавал rpcallowip=my_ip_server_...7.100

```
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18333           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8093/bitcoind
tcp6       0      0 :::18332                :::*                    LISTEN      8093/bitcoind
tcp6       0      0 :::18333                :::*                    LISTEN      8093/bitcoind
```

если через консоль пробую запустить курл

```
curl -s -u btc_user:btc_pass -X POST http://MY_SERVER_IP:18332/json_rpc -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "<id>", "method": "get_status", "params": {<params>}}'
```

начала возвращаться ошибка {"result":null,"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"},"id":null}

очень буду признателен за любую помощь

Comment: а curl установлен?

Comment: Никогда не читайте текст ошибок, сразу кидайте на SO, там разберутся.

Comment: – n.osennij , перепроверил да curl стоит все нормально

Comment: – u_mulder  я подозреваю что у меня нет подключения к ноде но как проверить это не пойму в строке браузера бросал к примеру такие комбинации http://user:password@MY_SERVER_IP:8332/ но он не работает   Не удается получить доступ к сайту  , порт еще пробовал 18332 но все также

Comment: @Евгений Колесник а если через консоль curl пробросить работает?

Comment: @Dmitriy  через консоль пробую команду bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo то да работает http://prntscr.com/lww4ru

Comment: @Dmitriy через консоль curl то ничего не возвращает , может не правильный запрос , сам запрос написал в вопросе в самом конце

Comment: @Dmitriy  {"result":null,"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"},"id":null}

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник, написано же в ошибке Parse error , мне кажется .json должен быть определённой структуры, чтобы скрипт на стороне сервера мог его распарсить правильно и вытащить данные.

Comment: мне кажется тут проблема с ип адресом портами или каким то доступом  я отхожу от правильного решения второстепенными ошибками

Answer (score 1):

решил проблему установив sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl